# Should we always use PipeWriter.GetMemory > Advance > Flush? When do we use WriteAsync?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I tried looking to the answer of this question, when I had the following problem.

Why do I read 16 bytes with value 0 after the first 16 valid bytes? Is it because we shouldn't use WriteAsync ever?

Example code:

```
var r = new Random();
Pipe testPipe = new Pipe();

var Buffer1 = new byte[16];
r.NextBytes(Buffer1);
await testPipe.Writer.WriteAsync(Buffer1);
testPipe.Writer.Advance(16);
await testPipe.Writer.FlushAsync();

var Buffer2 = new byte[16];
r.NextBytes(Buffer2);
await testPipe.Writer.WriteAsync(Buffer2);
testPipe.Writer.Advance(16);
await testPipe.Writer.FlushAsync();

var result = await testPipe.Reader.ReadAsync();
var Buffer3 = new byte[result.Buffer.Length];
result.Buffer.CopyTo(Buffer3.AsSpan());
```

There wasn't comprehensive coverage of all the information I needed about the two approaches, and I also had a problem that I didn't understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short version**

Don't call `Advance` after a `WriteAsync`, that's already called internally, that's only supposed to be used with the GetMemory pattern. Also, don't call FlushAsync, that's also already called internally.

```
var r = new Random();
Pipe testPipe = new Pipe();

var Buffer1 = new byte[16];
r.NextBytes(Buffer1);
await testPipe.Writer.WriteAsync(Buffer1);
//testPipe.Writer.Advance(16);
//await testPipe.Writer.FlushAsync();

var Buffer2 = new byte[16];
r.NextBytes(Buffer2);
await testPipe.Writer.WriteAsync(Buffer2);
//testPipe.Writer.Advance(16);
//await testPipe.Writer.FlushAsync();

var result = await testPipe.Reader.ReadAsync();
var Buffer3 = new byte[result.Buffer.Length];
result.Buffer.CopyTo(Buffer3.AsSpan());
```

**Long version**

`WriteAsync` already internally calls `Advance`:

In the source, `WriteAsync` is defined in https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.IO.Pipelines/src/System/IO/Pipelines/Pipe.DefaultPipeWriter.cs. That function simply calls the internal function on the pipe `return _pipe.WriteAsync(source, cancellationToken);`, that is defined in https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.IO.Pipelines/src/System/IO/Pipelines/Pipe.cs. That function calls `AdvanceCore` which is the underlying implementation of `Advance`.

It also internally calls `Flush`, so there's no need for that after `WriteAsync`. The `Flush` operation is the only one that is asynchronous.

The documentation for `WriteAsync` doesn't currently mention this behaviour - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipelines.pipewriter.writeasync?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

An author calls the use of `WriteAsync` bad - see https://mgravell.github.io/pipelines.docs/Writing/. This is because the PipeWriter it effectively uses the "GetMemory > Advance > Flush" approach internally. This means you get into the habit of creating a Memory buffer then copying it into the pipe memory which is inefficient. (The author doesn't mention the fact that there are APIs that still don't write to Memory and will only write to byte[])

When you have your own byte[] frame, it's probably more efficient to use `WriteAsync` because the coding appears to iterate and reuse through the available memory blocks sequentially. This prevents the creation of a new Memory block into the pool unnecessarily. The pool is there to minimise the creation and GC of objects, worrying about GC overhead (and memory page cache success?) more than a few more CPU cycles.

If you are using functions that support `Memory<byte>`, get the right sized Memory block using `PipeWriter.GetMemory`, then you can be writing directly to the buffer that will be forwarded through the pipe to the reader side.